# prepend a scalar to a vector

Tags: objective-c, vector

Say I have an existing vector x:

```
float x[4] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 4.0f, 8.0f};
```

How do a produce another vector that is exactly like x, but has the scalar 1.0 in the front position, making a 5 element vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
float y[5];
y[0] = 1.0f;
memcpy(&y[1], x, sizeof(x));
```

Comment: @CarlNorum Thanks. Take my +1 too.

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy` can do it for you:

```
float y[5] = { 1.0f };
memcpy(y + 1, x, sizeof x);
```